# Loop through array in instagram api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, instagram

I'm trying to loop through an array within instagram api. The array is Tags and after that I want each tag to append to a li element in my html. I've tried several things like a for loop within a foor loop. Now I've set it so the first element in the array Tags show but I want every tag to get it's own li tag, do I need to loop through the array called Tags or what? Thanks! Here's my code:

```
//instagram api example, this code makes you fetch images after searching specific hashtag
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myId = "---";
    //sets so form doesnt override jquery
    $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    })
    $('#submit').click(searchInst);
    //shows a loading bar when press the btn
    // Setup the url for the API
    //var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+input+"/media/recent?client_id=dff465e44a4d4026b554b3d7925643cc&callback=?&count=100";

    // Tell jQuery to fetch the data.
    // When it returns the data, it will call our `processImages` function 
    //$.getJSON(url, processImages);
    function searchInst() {
        $('.feed').empty()
        $('#load').append('<p>The images are loading..</p><br><img src="img/load.gif">')
        var input = $("#textInput").val()
        var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + input + '/media/recent?client_id=' + myId + '&callback=?&count=100'
        $.getJSON(url, processImages);
    };

    function processImages(chilibiff) {
        // The variable f represents the information we got back.
        var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < chilibiff.data.length; i++) {
            var f = chilibiff.data[i]
            var imgSrc = f.images.standard_resolution.url
            var userImg = f.user.profile_picture
            var userName = f.user.username
            //tag for loop doesn't work, try code for in on your server
            var tags = f.tags[0]
            $('.feed').append('<img src="' + userImg + '" id="profile"><p>' + userName + '</p>')
            $('.feed').append('<img src="' + imgSrc + '">')
            $('.feed').append('<li>' + tags + '</li>')
        }
        $('#load').empty()
    }
});
```

Comment: if you would provide some json data from API it would be more understandable. but you have also used jQuery so it's not.

Comment: Here is the json Data:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=396838.f59def8.f07fcba93f8747d599dec305f61ffbf0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so this will fix the problem. Need to loop through the array after you looped the results.

```
    //instagram api example, this code makes you fetch images after searching specific hashtag

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var myId = "------";

    //sets so form doesnt override jquery
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
})

      $('#submit').click(searchInst);

      //shows a loading bar when press the btn

     // Setup the url for the API
    //var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+input+"/media/recent?   client_id=dff465e44a4d4026b554b3d7925643cc&callback=?&count=100";

    // Tell jQuery to fetch the data.
    // When it returns the data, it will call our `processImages` function 
    //$.getJSON(url, processImages);

    function searchInst() {
$('.feed').empty()
$('#load').append('<p>The images are loading..</p><br><img src="img/load.gif">')
var input = $("#textInput").val()
var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + input + '/media/recent?client_id=' +    myId + '&callback=?&count=100'
$.getJSON(url, processImages);
    };

    function processImages(chilibiff) {
    // The variable f represents the information we got back.
    for (var i = 0; i < chilibiff.data.length; i++) {
    var f = chilibiff.data[i]
    var imgSrc = f.images.standard_resolution.url
    var userImg = f.user.profile_picture
    var userName = f.user.username
    //tag for loop doesn't work, try code for in on your server
    $('.feed').append('<img src="' + imgSrc + '">')
    $('.feed').append('<img src="' + userImg + '" id="profile">' + '<p><a   href="http://www.instagram.com/' + userName + '" target="_blank">' + userName + '</a></p>')

  for (var x=0; x < f.tags.length; x++) {
  var tag = f.tags[x]
  $('.feed').append('<li>' + tag + '</li>')
    }

    }

    $('#load').empty()
    }


    });
```